# Merging std::sets into std::vector

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, stdvector, stdset

Consider the following.

I have two `std::set`s and want to merge them in the `std::vector` in sorted order.

Which is the most effective way to do that?

I did something like this, but I think that there must be a better way of doing it.

```
std::set<int> S1;
std::set<int> S2;
// ....
// Initialization of sets
// ....

std::vector V;

std::set<int>::iterator iter;

for(iter = S1.begin(); iter!=S1.end(); ++iter)
{
    V.push_back(*iter);
}

for(iter = S2.begin(); iter!=S2.end(); ++iter)
{
    V.push_back(*iter);
}

std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
```

Here is my code, is there more effective way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

std::merge should do the trick, since S1 and S2 are sorted:

```
// Initialization of sets
// ....
std::vector V;

std::merge(S1.begin(), S1.end(), S2.begin(), S2.end(), std::back_inserter(V));
```

// instead of V.begin() -- thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify your code by using `std::copy()`:

```
std::copy(S1.begin(), S1.end(), std::back_inserter(V));
std::copy(S2.begin(), S2.end(), std::back_inserter(V));
std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
```

Comment: I guess the copy does the same iteration as for in my code, why this is more effective?

Comment: It is probably not. It will just make the intention more clear.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan - Not only is the intention clearer, it also guarantees it will work.  You can't overlook the many times programmers make silly mistakes writing hand-coded loops.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: True, but it's just as easy to make silly mistakes with the standard algorithms (e.g. forgetting to use `back_inserter`). I've already had to correct two answers to this question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - Yes, but those mistakes using the standard algorithms (for the most part) boil down to compile-time mistakes, while coding a mistake in a loop will usually pass compilation but show up at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The sets are already sorted, so it does seem wasteful to re-sort it all again at the end.

How about something like this (left a couple of TODOs as an excercise for the reader!):

```
  std::set<int>iterator S1iter = S1.begin();
  std::set<int>iterator S1iter = S2.begin();

  while( S1iter != S1.end() && S2iter != S2.end() ) {

    if( S1iter == S1.end() ) {
       //TODO:  S1 is finished, so push back range S2iter->S2.end()
       //       onto the vector
       break;
    }
    else if( S2iter == S2.end() ) {
       //TODO:  S2 is finished, so push back range S1iter->S1.end()
       //       onto the vector
       break;
    }
    else if( *S1iter < *S2iter ) {
      V.push_back( *S1iter );
      ++S1iter;
    }
    else {
      V.push_back( *S2iter );
      ++S2iter;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Taking the sets as already sorted, a simple `std::merge()` should do the trick, as already suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::merge(): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge

Its implementation is similar to yours.

Comment: I suspect the implementation isn't similar, since its complexity is `O(N)` rather than `O(N*log(N))`.